# What are the different types of energy transfer?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, forces, energy, work

[NOTE: The definition of work that I am using is the following-

> Work is the transfer of energy that occurs to/from an object when a force acts on it to cause a displacement.

]

In my physics book it says:

> The only type of energy transfer that we have considered is work $W$ done on a system by an external force.

This made me wonder what are the other kinds of energy transfer? While searching about it on the internet I found that $Heat$ transfer is a type of energy transfer which can occur as conduction, convection and radiation. But thinking deeper about these I found that since conduction occurs via interaction caused by the forces that act between different atoms and hence the energy transfer is essentially the work done by the forces. Same goes for convection though here the particles are free to move and the transfer occurs under the influence of gravity. Whereas radiation is transfered via photons which are themselves the force carries of EM force.

So in this way it looks like the transfer of energy requires forces and hence work to be done. So why does the book state so? Am I missing something over here? If whatever I have concluded in the previous paragraph is wrong then what are the different types of energy transfer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi friend Photons are not force carriers,they are the so called "particles" of light.They carry energy and momentum.

Comment: @Unique [This](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_carrier) Wikipedia article states :"Photons, W bosons, and Z bosons, excitations of the electroweak gauge fields"

Comment: @Unique And [this one](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon)    states "It is the quantum of the electromagnetic field including electromagnetic radiation such as light and radio waves, and the *force carrier* for the electromagnetic force"

Comment: The article says that they give rise to forces.But I think that force is not a sort of "object" which can be carried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Work is the transfer of energy that occurs to/from an object when a
>   force acts on it to cause a displacement.

With regard to differentiating energy transfer by heat vs work, the key term in this definition is *displacement*. In the case of heat transfer, in no case is there a *net* force causing a *net* displacement of the atoms and molecules of the substances involved with heat transfer.

Although in the case of heat transfer by convection there is movement the fluid, that movement occurs after heat is transferred by conduction between a surface and thin layer of fluid in contact with that surface. The movement of the fluid away from the thin layer is the result of mechanical work resulting from pressure gradients and gravity.

> So in this way it looks like the transfer of energy requires forces
>   and hence work to be done. So why does the book state so? Am I missing
>   something over here? If whatever I have concluded in the previous
>   paragraph is wrong then what are the different types of energy
>   transfer?

While both heat and work energy transfers may involve forces, work involves a net force and net displacement of mass. For heat forces may be associated with the collisions of atoms and molecules resulting in transfer of kinetic energy, but there is no net displacement of the center of mass of the collection of those atoms and molecules resulting from those forces.

We are left with two types of energy transfer. Heat and work. There may be various forms and mechanisms associated with them, they are nonetheless different.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are asking about how are heat transfer and mechanical energy transfer different.

All the modes of energy transfer mentioned in the question are the modes of heat transfer.Heat is the energy in transit which is very much different from mechanical work.I think that the modes you mentioned must be known to you.The mechanical energy transfer can be easily understood by the equations given below.

> The only type of energy transfer that we have considered is work W done on a system by an external force.

Basically the book is talking about mechanical work.The above statement can be uniquely expressed in the following equation:-
$$\Delta E_{mechanical}=W_{external}+W_{non conservative}$$

While by the first law of thermodynamics you can relate the mechanical work done by/on the system,the heat transferred/absorbed by the system and change in its internal energy.
$$\Delta Q=\Delta U_{system}+W_{system}$$